# CMakeLists cannot find opencv library, although i defined it

Tags: opencv, cmake, ros

I try using ROS with opencv, but when I 'catkin-make', it gives me this:

```
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  fls_package/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/vered/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/vered/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:318: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

with cmake-gui, I defined:
1. CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = /home/vered/opencv/build (where OpenCVConfig.cmake is)
2. OpenCV_DIR = /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2 (where opencv.hpp is)

configured, generated and then sudo make install,

and still when catkin-make, i've got the same problem.
any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn’t `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` include the directory containing the OpenCVConfig.cmake file?

Comment: you right, edited:) still not working

Comment: Message `Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` means that variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should specify the directory, which you have passed to `cmake` when configure OpenCV. Message `...set "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.` means that the directory, specified in `OpenCV_DIR` variable, should contain `OpenCVConfig.cmake` or `opencv-config.cmake` file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that i tried all the solutions in the site, except this one:
[ROS "catkin_make" cannot find OpenCVConfig.cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616203/ros-catkin-make-cannot-find-opencvconfig-cmake?rq=1)
and that's what worked for me...